# I have throw Exception A99 NO Command received in Invalid state. What does it mean?

Tags: flags

I am trying to delete a message and I used `message.setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);` but It doesn't work for me and throw exception. What I did wrong??.This this my code:

```
public class TestList extends javax.swing.JFrame
{

    private JList theList;
    private Folder inbox;

    public TestList()
    {
        initComponents();
    }

    private TestList(JList deleteInput)
    {
        theList = deleteInput;
        try
        {
            final
            String IMAP_ADDER = "webmail.swan.ac.uk";
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null); //Get the swssion
            Store store = session.getStore("imaps"); //Get the store
            store.connect(IMAP_ADDER, "username", "password");
            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX"); //Get the folder
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
            System.out.
            println(inbox);
            int i = theList.getSelectedIndex();
            Email email = (Email) theList.getModel().getElementAt(i);
            Message message = email.getMessage();
            System.out.
            println(message);
            message.setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);
            /* Throw Exception A99 NO Command received in Invalid state.;*/
            System.out.
            println("delete");
            inbox.close(true);
            inbox.expunge();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 'and throw exception' -> which exception?

Comment: This one: Throw Exception A99 NO Command received in Invalid state. What does it mean?

Comment: ops sorry.. i didn't saw that... The "NO Command received in Invalid state." means the IMAP folder (account) is read-only.

Comment: Thanx it is work now, but I need to close the window andopen it again to see that the message was delete. Is there a way to delete message straight away without need to close the window and open it again to see the result?

Comment: Where did you load the messages into your list? can you reload again?

Comment: What Iam doing is selecting the message I want to delete from the JList and I press the delete button to delete the message. However, it is deleting but not completely.

Comment: Does this  inbox.close(true) not save your changes ?

Comment: I don't know why the message it is delete but not showing to me immediately?

Answer (score 3):

The "A9 NO Command received in Invalid state." means the IMAP folder (the account) is read-only. Check with your Engineering team. They might have not set up the "Write" permission to that IMAP folder.